# Python не выполняет цикл

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
n = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
d = a
d1 = n-1
if a>0:
    while d1>0:
        a +=d
        d1 -=1
        print(a)
elif a<0:
    while d1>0:
        a +=d
        d1 -=1
        print(a)
elif n<0:
    c = a
    c1 = n-1
    while c1<0:
        c1 +=1
        a -=c
        print(a)
```

Всё работает, ошибок нет, но если вводить второе число отрицательным, то не выводит 'a'. Просто ввёл числа сам, и на этом конец программы

Comment: Если второе число ввести отрицательным, то как будет выполняться условие d1>0 ?

Comment: Но ведь, если n<0, то выполняется код, который снизу, а остальное игнорируется?

Comment: До этого условия просто может не дойти. У тебя а>0, выполняется if, и в этом же if не выполняется while.

Answer (score 0):

Условие

```
 elif n<0:
```

Выполнится только если  a<=0 и n<0.

Если вы вводите a>0 и n<0 то под этот случай у вас нет условия и операторов.

Для a и n всего есть 4 случая

```
 a>0, n>0
 a>0, n<=0
 a<=0, n>0
 a<=0, n<=0
```